Uniqueness of a canonical homography decomposition
Consider a multi-camera system with $n \geq 3$ calibrated cameras, each represented by a projection matrix $P_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 4}$ for $i=1, \dots, n$. We first want to detect and track people and objects in a dynamic environment, and the classify people as either customers or customer representatives and objects as specific types (e.g., iPhone, Bluetooth speaker). When setting up the cameras and using object detection models (e.g. YOLOv3) for the first model and a classification model as the second model (e.g ResNet) for the second model, we have faced these challenges

Occlusion: People and objects can partially or fully occlude each other, making it difficult to track them consistently across all cameras. This makes it difficult to track relevant metrics such as how many customers bought a certain product or how long were customers and customer representative interacting with each other.
Non-Planarity: People and objects are inherently non-planar, and existing off the shelf pose estimation methods don't seem to be good enough for our use case.
Tracking: The detection and tracking system needs to operate in real-time to be useful in practical applications. Current tracking algorithms like KCF are not accurate/precise enough.

Suppose a person can be represented as a rigid, non-planar object in each camera's image plane, resulting in a set of corresponding image points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $x_i \in \mathbb{P}^2$. Assume that the correspondences are exact and that the object spans at least four non-coplanar points in 3D space.
Let $H_i \in \mathbb{P}^{3 \times 3}$ be a homography that maps a canonical object model to the observed image points in camera $i$. We can decompose $H_i$ as $H_i = K_i [R_i | t_i]$, where $K_i$ is the known camera's intrinsic matrix, $R_i \in SO(3)$ is a rotation, and $t_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a translation.
Question. Are the following statements true or are there any references related to the specific study of these problems?
There exists a unique decomposition of the homographies $\{H_i\}$ into rotations $\{R_i\}$ and translations $\{t_i\}$ that satisfies the following conditions:

The rotations and translations represent a rigid transformation of the same object across all cameras. This implies that for any two cameras $i$ and $j$, there exists a single rotation $R$ and translation $t$ such that $R_j = R R_i$ and $t_j = R t_i + t$.

The decomposition is unique up to a global rotation and translation of the object. This means that if $\{R_i', t_i'\}$ is another decomposition satisfying the consistency condition, then there exists a single rotation $R_0 \in SO(3)$ and translation $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $R_i' = R_0 R_i$ and $t_i' = R_0 t_i + t_0$ for all $i$.


A unique and consistent decomposition would lead to more accurate and robust 3D pose estimation of people and objects, even in the presence of occlusions. I think it would also at least establish that there could be much better tracking algorithms that could better predict the position of a person frame to frame. In other words, if we have a benchmark tracking algorithm maybe we could determine how much better we could do (not necessarily the details of the specific tracking algorithm).
Apologies in advance if this is known result already/elementary question.
